# How to use ovs connect 2 namespace to 2 bridge?

Tags: namespaces, bridge, openvswitch, sfc

I want to build five clients through two interconnected bridges to reach the other end of the server.

Just like this final result:
[Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxewd.png)

I have tried a client to connect to the server through two interconnected bridges.

But unsuccessful.

Like this:
[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0dmS.png)

Is there need additional route table or ARP?

Comment: How you connect two bridges using patch port? show us the dump flows of the both bridges

Comment: switch1 config:
sudo ovs-vsctl add-br br0
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth3   (linking to another switch use the cable)
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 patch0
sudo ovs-vsctl set interface patch0 type=patch
sudo ovs-vsctl set interface patch0 options:peer=patch1
sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth1     (host)
sudo ovs-vsctl set-controller br0 tcp:192.168.1.2:6633
sudo ifconfig br0 192.168.2.232 netmask 255.255.255.0